# Cognito use either email or phone number as username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I have this SAM template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Passwordless SMS authentication backend using Amazon Cognito User Pools CUSTOM AUTH challenge flow w/ AWS Lambda triggers and Amazon SNS for sending SMS TOTP

Metadata:
  AWS::ServerlessRepo::Application:
    Name: passwordless-sms-email-auth 
    Description: >
      Passwordless SMS authentication backend using Amazon Cognito User Pools CUSTOM AUTH challenge flow w/ AWS Lambda triggers and Amazon SNS for sending SMS TOTP
    SpdxLicenseId: MIT
    LicenseUrl: LICENSE
    Labels: ['passwordless', 'authentication', 'cognito', 'auth', 'sms', 'iOS', 'mobile', 'pinpoint', 'serverless', 'amplify']
    SemanticVersion: 1.14.20

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Parameters:
  UserPoolName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name you want the User Pool to be created with
    Default: rafaelTest

Resources:
  UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Ref UserPoolName
      Schema:
        - Name: name
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
        - Name: phone_number
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: false
        - Name: email
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: false
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 6
          RequireLowercase: false
          RequireNumbers: false
          RequireSymbols: false
          RequireUppercase: false
      UsernameAttributes:
        - phone_number
        - email
      MfaConfiguration: "OFF"
      LambdaConfig:
        CreateAuthChallenge: !GetAtt CreateAuthChallenge.Arn
        DefineAuthChallenge: !GetAtt DefineAuthChallenge.Arn
        PreSignUp: !GetAtt PreSignUp.Arn
        VerifyAuthChallengeResponse: !GetAtt VerifyAuthChallengeResponse.Arn

  UserPoolClient:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient"
    Properties:
      ClientName: sms-auth-client
      GenerateSecret: false
      UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - CUSTOM_AUTH_FLOW_ONLY

Outputs:
  UserPoolId:
    Description: ID of the User Pool
    Value: !Ref UserPool
  UserPoolClientId:
    Description: ID of the User Pool Client
    Value: !Ref UserPoolClient
```

When creating the userpool, I wanted users to be able to use either just their email or just their phone as their username.

This way it is done, I always need to send both email and phone number.

Does anyone know how I solve this?

I want users to be able to log in by putting one of the following information:

- email + name
- phone number + name

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Users can login with their email or phone number, using this SAM template and use a random uuid as username when sign up.

```yaml
UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Ref UserPoolName
      Schema:
        - Name: phone_number
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
        - Name: email
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 6
          RequireLowercase: false
          RequireNumbers: false
          RequireSymbols: false
          RequireUppercase: false
      AliasAttributes:
        - email
        - phone_number
      MfaConfiguration: "OFF"
```

But now I need to know with alias users use on sign in, anyone know how?

i'm doing a passwordless flow with cognito and the event on create-auth-lambda triggers is always the same.